# How to update the variable in tf.variable_scope with variable's name?

Tags: tensorflow, scope

I want to modification the value about variable 'weight1' in tf.variable_scope.

I try to modification the value by other function, but it not work follow me.

```
def inference(q, reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope('layer1', reuse = reuse):
        x = tf.get_variable('weight1', [1, 3], initializer = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev = 0.1))
        y = tf.get_variable('weight2', [3, 1], initializer = tf.constant_initializer([[1],[2],[3]]))
    return tf.matmul(x, y)



def update_process(reuse=True):
    with tf.variable_scope('layer1', reuse = reuse):
        x = tf.get_variable('weight1',[1, 3])
        update=tf.assign(x, x-1)

        with tf.Session() as sess:
            sess.run(init)
            print(sess.run(x))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()    

z = inference(1)            
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(5):
        update_process(reuse = True)
        print(sess.run(z))
        print('\n')
```

I want to this code output different list about sess.run(z), but the value is always same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run `sess.run(update)` in `update_process` in the same session that the `inference` part of the graph runs:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def inference(q, reuse=False):
    with tf.variable_scope('layer1', reuse = reuse):
        x = tf.get_variable('weight1', [1, 3], initializer = tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev = 0.1))
        y = tf.get_variable('weight2', [3, 1], initializer = tf.constant_initializer([[1],[2],[3]]))
    return tf.matmul(x, y)



def update_process(reuse=True):
    with tf.variable_scope('layer1', reuse = reuse):
        x = tf.get_variable('weight1',[1, 3])
        update=tf.assign(x, x-1)
        print(sess.run(update))


z = inference(1)            
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()    
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(5):
        update_process(reuse = True)
        print(sess.run(z))
        print('\n')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You have helped me a lot.